# What on earth is Microsoft Word wildcard search * replace doing in this case?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2013

I'm trying to get Microsoft Word wildcard search and replace to add `<b>` on either side of blocks of bold-formatted characters. I've tried many things, none of which have done quite what I need, but this example makes no sense to me.

My search was:

Find what: `(<[abo827]@>)`
Options: Use Wildcards
Format: Font: Bold

Replace with: `<b>\1<b>`

The test document contained two sections in bold:

```
82o
7b
```

The result I expected was:

```
<b>82o<b>
<b>7b<b>
```

What it did instead was:

```
<82b><b><b>o<b>
<b7><b><b>a<b>
```

That baffles me, because:

1. It seems to think it should split strings of numbers from letters (also punctuation like commas and periods from brackets).
2. I have NO idea why it would put the number part INSIDE the `<b>` that is supposed to go before it.
3. I have NO idea why it would put one number before the b, and then the other number after the b.

Does anyone have any idea what on earth is going on here?

Does anyone know how to replace all strings of bold characters with the same string but having `<b>` on either side of it?

Comment: I get the expected result, but to do so had to change `(<[ao827]@>)` to `(<[abo827]@>)` to have the second line be found

Comment: Thanks. I think the missing 'b' was just my typo in this post. If you get the expected result, then I wonder what caused me to get the weird split results. It seemed determined to split strings of numbers from letters and punctuation. I eventually worked around it by loading it it OpenOffice and using [:alpha:]@ ...